# Windows Sleep Mode - Hardware not booting up

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, boot, cpu, sleep

I have a problem with my computers. It's mainly on my ASUS Eee PC Seashell 1215n Laptop, but other people I know have said that this happens to them too.

Sometimes when I wake up my laptop, it turns on and I can here the fan spinning around inside, but the screen stays black and my laptop has a CPU Light, and it does not flash as it normally does when it boots normally. As I noted, it only happens sometimes, and not on all my computers. My laptop has Windows 7 and Windows 8 and is dual bootable, and it happens on both operating systems.

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try disabling the "S3" sleep mode in the BIOS. I can't promise it'll help but that kind of thing was sometimes problematic when Vista was new - it varied widely by manufacturer and even BIOS revision. If S3 was disabled, try enabling it instead. Also consider hibernation vs. sleep if you have the storage space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went into the BIOS and changed the S3 sleep mode setting. It is no longer doing this 'sleep bug' any more.